# Test harness tool for executing Java web services

Tags: java, web-services

Can somebody suggest test harness tool for executing Java web services for testing purposes?

Comment: What do you want to test? Performance or function?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SOAP UI tool.
Thanks
Ramakrishna.

Answer (score 0):

While soapUI is good., it only let's your web service end points be tested as a whole. This is good from a continous integration point of view.

The problem is that you can't use soap ui for unit testing because you can't really mock out the dependencies of your web services.

For this very reason, we decided to use Apache CXF as our web service framework of choice. Apache CXF is tightly coupled with Spring, thus allowing you to leverage features such as dependency injection into your Web service classes. You should take a look at Apache CXF if ease of development and unit testing is your goal.